# Python.How do I have this function return an integer instead of a list?

Tags: python

This function takes a string input, removes punctuation, counts the number of letters in each word and returns the number of letters of the shortest word in the original string. However it returns the answer as a list. I need it to return the result as an integer.It returns [2] in this given example and I need it to return 2. How should I modify this code?

```
def find_short(s):
    import string
    string_no_punct = s.strip(string.punctuation) 
    word_lenght_list = list(map(len, string_no_punct.split()))
    word_lenght_list.sort()
    new_list = word_lenght_list[:1]
    return new_list
print(find_short("Tomorrow will be another day!"))
```

Comment: `return new_list[0]` or use `new_list = word_lenght_list[0]` to get an `int` to begin with

Comment: Thank you Nick. I wanted to choose your answer as the correct one but I can't do it because it is a comment.

Comment: return int(new_list[0])

Comment: or just return new_list[0]

Comment: ... and it should remain a comment.  How to access a list element is covered in any tutorial on lists.  Remember, this is an archive of useful answers for professional and enthusiast programmers ... not a "help site".  I'm glad your problem is solved, but this is not something to add to our data base.

Comment: Prune, I understand what this website is about. I am working on becoming a professional programmer. Your comment  was of no use to me as a new user.  Actually, it was discouraging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that

```
word_lenght_list[:1]
```

is a slicing operation, returning a list containing all elements of `word_lenght_list` from `0` to `1-1` i.e. `0`, so you get a list `[2]` in your example case. To get the smallest value in `word_lenght_list`, just use `word_lenght_list[0]` instead.

A better solution is to skip the `sort` and just use `min`:

```
def find_short(s):
    import string
    string_no_punct = s.strip(string.punctuation) 
    word_length_list = list(map(len, string_no_punct.split()))
    new_list = min(word_length_list)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Your new code should look like this:

```py
def find_short(s): 
    import string
    string_no_punct = s.strip(string.punctuation) 
    word_lenght_list = list(map(len, string_no_punct.split())) 
    word_lenght_list.sort() 
    new_list = word_lenght_list[:1] 
    return new_list[0] 
print(find_short("Tomorrow will be another day!"))
```

Just change `return new_list` to `return new_list[0]`

Comment: Sorry for the weird formatting issues at first, im on mobile and it didnt seem to like copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
new_list = word_lenght_list[:1]
```

this [:1] is a slicing notation. When you slice a list, it returns a list, when you slice a string, it returns a string. That's why you're getting list instead of int